# Html body attributes converted into XPages

Tags: xpages

I’d like to have a (body) containing the attributes data-target, data-spy and data-twwttr-rendered and finally look like this:

```html
<body data-target=".bs-docs-sidebar" data-spy="scroll" data-twttr-rendered="true">
```

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible server side by default. You have to override the existing *ViewRootRenderer*.

1.
Create a new Java class which extends the existing ViewRootRenderer of XPages. This class has to override the method *encodeHtmlBodyStart* which generates the HTML code of the *body* attribute:

```
package ch.hasselba.jsf;

import com.ibm.commons.util.StringUtil;
import com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ViewRootRenderer extends
    com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.ViewRootRendererEx2 {

    @Override
    protected void encodeHtmlBodyStart(FacesContext fc, UIViewRootEx uiRoot,
        ResponseWriter rw) throws IOException {

        String str = null;

        // begin with body element
        rw.startElement("body", uiRoot);

        // add style attribute
        str = uiRoot.getStyle();
        if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(str)) {
            rw.writeAttribute("style", str, "style");
        }

        // add class attribute
        str = uiRoot.getStyleClass();
        if (StringUtil.isNotEmpty(str)) {
            rw.writeAttribute("class", str, "styleClass");
        }

        // add your own attributes here
        rw.writeAttribute("data-target", ".bs-docs-sidebar", "data-target");
        rw.writeAttribute("data-spy", "scroll", "data-spy");
        rw.writeAttribute("data-twttr-rendered", "true", "data-twttr-rendered");

        // add new line
        writeln(rw);

    }
}
```

As you can see, the attributes you want to add are hardcoded above. The code before the hardcoded part (*style* & *class* attribute) is required because this is the default code.

2.
Register this *ViewRootRenderer* in the *faces-config.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.ViewRoot</component-family>
            <renderer-type>ch.hasselba.jsf.ViewRootRenderer</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>ch.hasselba.jsf.ViewRootRenderer</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

3.
Use the *renderedType* property of your XPage to add this Renderer instead of the default one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    rendererType="ch.hasselba.jsf.ViewRootRenderer">
</xp:view>
```

This is the way to add the renderer to a specific XPage only. If you want to override it in the whole application, you have to change the existing *renderer-class* (Step 2).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.ViewRoot</component-family>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.xsp.ViewRootEx</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>ch.hasselba.jsf.ViewRootRenderer</renderer-class>              
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

You can skip Step 3 now, but be aware that this affects every XPage in your application.

Comment: Great solution! I tried to do it with the "out of the box" possibilities like themes but no way to get it to work. So I ended up with my client side solution. But, yours is perfect.

Comment: I know this is old, just confirming on Domino/Designer 9.01 FP10 (5 years later) - this is still a working solution.  I did not do step 3 editing the default renderer and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the body attributes on `onClientLoad` event:

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        document.body.setAttribute('data-target', '.bs-docs-sidebar'); 
        document.body.setAttribute('data-spy', 'scroll'); 
        document.body.setAttribute('data-twttr-rendered', 'true'); 
        ]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

The rendered page body has then the attributes you wanted:

[image]